# Convex Hull - Higher Dimension (20D)

Tags: scipy, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I'm trying to find the convex hull vertices of a Higher Dimension Data (20 D). I have found open source alogorithms by QHULL which can handle upto 8D and sometimes 9D with less points.Are there any algorithms that can handle 20 Dimensions or more? Computation time is not an issue.

Comment: Please be more specific with respect to the programming language.

Comment: I require the algorithm in Python. But QHULL is open source available inbuilt in Python Scipy and Matlab.

Comment: I am looking for the similar thing, I want to find the volume of 15 dimensional convex figure. Did you find it?